# Jetpack compose mutableStateOf list doesn't trigger re-composition when changing property value in list item class

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, data-class, compose-recomposition

I think I'm missing a core concept of Jetpack Compose here. I'm running into an issue when I'm trying to change a `non-constructor` `data class` `property` inside of a composable when this composable is part of an observed list.

Does not work: (`sadProperty` is not declared in the constructor)

```
data class IntWrapper(val actualInt: Int = 0) {
var sadProperty: Int = 0
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun test() {
var state by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf(IntWrapper(1), IntWrapper(2), IntWrapper(3),IntWrapper(4)))}

    fun onClick(item: IntWrapper) {
        val indexOf = state.indexOf(item)
        val newState = state.minus(item).toMutableList()
        val copy = item.copy()
        copy.sadProperty = Random.nextInt()
        newState.add(indexOf, copy)
        state = newState
    }
    
    Column() {
        for (item in state) {
            Text("ac: ${item.actualInt} sad: ${item.sadProperty}", modifier = Modifier.clickable { onClick(item)})
        }
    }

}
```

Works: (`actualInt` is declared in the constructor)

```
data class IntWrapper(var actualInt: Int = 0) {
var sadProperty: Int = 0
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun test() {
var state by remember { mutableStateOf(listOf(IntWrapper(1), IntWrapper(2), IntWrapper(3),IntWrapper(4)))}

    fun onClick(item: IntWrapper) {
        val indexOf = state.indexOf(item)
        val newState = state.minus(item).toMutableList()
        val copy = item.copy()
        copy.actualInt = Random.nextInt()
        newState.add(indexOf, copy)
        state = newState
    }
    
    Column() {
        for (item in state) {
            Text("ac: ${item.actualInt} sad: ${item.sadProperty}", modifier = Modifier.clickable { onClick(item)})
        }
    }

}
```

Could somebody explain why this happens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a question of both `Jetpack Compose` and about `Kotlin` data class, bare with me, I'll try my best.

Lets start with Kotlin's Data classes first

As per the [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) about `Data Class`

> The compiler automatically derives the following members from all
> properties declared in the primary constructor:
>
> - equals()/hashCode() pair
> - toString() of the form "User(name=John, age=42)"
> - componentN() functions corresponding to the properties in their order of declaration.
> - copy() .

Your `IntWrapper` data class has one **Primary Constructor**, the parenthesis that follows the class name, and with 1 property declared inside of it.

```
data class IntWrapper(val actualInt: Int = 0) {
      var sadProperty: Int = 0
}
```

with that, we can say, your `IntWrapper` data class has

- 1 component (`actualInt`)
- toString() of the form `IntWrapper(actualInt=?)`
- a generated `copy()` function
- a generated equals()/hashCode() pair

and based again from the [docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html):

> The compiler only uses the properties defined inside the primary
> constructor for the automatically generated functions. To exclude a
> property from the generated implementations, declare it inside the
> class body:

The `equals` will only use/evaluate the property declared from `IntWrapper's` primary constructor (i.e `actualInt : Int`), and `sadProperty` is excluded from it because its in the part of the data class body.

Now consider the following:

```
val intWrapper1 = IntWrapper(actualInt = 5)
intWrapper1.sadProperty = 5

val intWrapper2 = IntWrapper(actualInt = 5)
intWrapper2.sadProperty = 10

Log.e("AreTheyEqual?", "${intWrapper1 == intWrapper2}")
```

it prints,

```
E/AreTheyEqual?: true
```

because the `equality` sees both of the derived properties have the same value `5`, `sadProperty` is excluded from this comparison.

```
val intWrapper1 = IntWrapper(actualInt = 5)
intWrapper1.sadProperty = 5

val intWrapper2 = IntWrapper(actualInt = 10)
intWrapper2.sadProperty = 5
```

prints,

```
E/AreTheyEqual?: false
```

because the generated equals verifies that the generated component (`actualInt`) is NOT the same from the two `IntWrapper` instance.

Now going to `Jetpack Compose`, applying everything we understand with data classes,

- The first `test` complies with everything about `data class`, it creates a new object with a new value and that's what `Compose` needs to trigger `re-composition`.
- The second `test` will not trigger `re-composition`, `Compose` still sees the same `IntWrapper` instance because `sadProperty` is not part of the generated components that will be used by the data class's equals operation.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be this obvious... Can't believe I missed it, thank you for the clear and concise explanation!

Answer (score 0):

In Compose, you must use one of the following two methods to perform the recomposition operation successfully:

1 - using mutableStateListOf(), however, by updating the value of the item in the list, the recomposition operation is performed

2- Using your own method that you posted

But for the second method, you need to tell Compose that actualInt has changed, so you need to create a new instance of int.

If you don't want to do this, you need to explain your scenario more so that I can provide a more complete guide